# Mixin with access-functionality in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a working VueJs application, and when a user logs in, he gets some rights from the server like administrator, readOnlyUser, worker etc.  Based on these privileges, some components/functionality in the application should be or, should not be available to the user. For an example I would like to put a reference to an access-right method on my differenct components/divs:

```
<MyComponent v-if="hasRights()"></MyComponent>
```

Or just access this method from the script section. 
I am thinking of using mixins, this seem to suit my needs, but is mixin´s the right way to solve this issue? Are there another more patten-like correct way to do it?

Comment: Can do it with vuex state management https://vuex.vuejs.org/.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for architecture:
Create files per rights:

- Admin.js
- User1.js
- User2.js
  etc.

Now you can create a function (wherever that takes in the user from your server, and then referes you to the right file. By doing this you can call in . your components: `this.$config.get().displaySomething` . Where the `get()` knows which file to go to. Make your config available on bootstrap.
The reason I don't recommend vuex is since it sounds like your config is static and can just be hard coded into file.